# Sending MMS on iPhone using CoreTelephony

Tags: iphone, ios, mms, iphone-privateapi, core-telephony

I am interested in sending an MMS within a private application on the iPhone. A lot of the information I need is proprietary, and therefore I can't find it anywhere. Basically, I'm looking for the proper way to construct a CTMessage and encode it for MMS, and then sending it via one of the overloaded sendMMS functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you managed to send an MMS this way ?
I always get errors when trying to transforme my CTMessage in something the CTMessageCenter can send via sendMMS or else.
Any Help would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested: here is what I managed to dig up (&/OR piece together myself).

For every MMS, a CTMessage is allocated & initialized. addRecipient/setRecipient is called to do just that.

For each data/text section a CTMessagePart is built with its data and corresponding datatype, and then added to the CTMessage's items array. The first item in each MMS items array is always a CTMessagePart containing a SMIL-formatted layout that the recipient interprets to display the message. Each CTMessagePart following the first is in the order that it is referenced from the SMIL data.

Each (unmodifiied) iPhone has an instance of CTMessageCenter running, with the id sharedMessageCenter. Calling sharedMessageCenter's sendMMS, giving the id of the CTMessage you just created will automate the rest of the process. Essentially, the CTMessage is encoded using the CTMmsEncoder into an MMS-PDU hex string. (Not to sure of the correct name for it, hah). Anyways, sharedMessageCenter's send method will then send the (encoded) MMS to your provider's MMSC.

That pretty much sums it up, and should give anyone looking to head down that path a good place to start depending on what they're doing. I can do my best to answer any questions.

Comment: Did you managed to send an MMS this way ? I always get errors when trying to transforme my CTMessage in something the CTMessageCenter can send via sendMMS or else. Any Help would be great

Comment: So, what I'd suggest is that you look into capturing a live MMS, e.g. Send yourself one, and then break down each portion of it. decodeMMS will give you a little insight as to how non-text data fields are encoded. Modify the message fields, and voila! You've much less work to do. I was able to send MMS messages using CTMessageCenter's send()